# Error when using _mm256_load_ps() Intel intrinsic

Tags: c, intel, simd

I've tried to use the _mm256_load_ps() intrinsic to make my program run faster. Meaning that I want to load 8 floats at a time and store them in a 266b vector to use them for further computations.

```
/* code snipet */
a_vec = _mm256_load_ps(&a[0])
b_vec = _mm256_load_ps(&b[0])
res   = _mm256_addsub_ps(a,b)
/* code snipet */
```

Also, I used these flags in my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -c -Wall -O5 -mavx -mfma -ffast-math
```

And I've made sure that my processor supports AVX extensions. But when I compile my code, I keep getting this warning:

**warning: AVX vector return without AVX enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]**

PS : I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bits

Comment: Is this 32-bit code? What operating system are you targeting? The ABI probably doesn't let you return values in AVX registers. I *assume* there is a `return` statement there in the `/* code snipet */` part that you've hidden from us.

Comment: One more thing to add ... I'm transforming my code from 128b vector to a 256b vector and I haven't change the alignment could be that the problem!!? Also I made an in-place code so there is no return.

Comment: @A.nechi AVX relaxes the alignment requirements compared to SSE, but `_mm256_load_ps()` is an explicitly aligned load (`MOVAPS`), which *does* require 32-bit alignment.

Comment: Can we see the actual build commands that are emitted when you type `make` ?

Comment: @EOF: [`_mm256_load_ps()` requires 32 *byte* alignment.](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_load_ps&expand=3073)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Makefile or something else in your build is broken.  `-O5 -mavx` definitely enables AVX, so that warning tells us your compiler isn't seeing those options.

Presumably, your code doesn't compile at all, and there are error messages later. `_mm256_load_ps` isn't recognized without AVX support enabled.

This code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256 foo(const float *a, const float *b)
{
   __m256 a_vec = _mm256_load_ps(&a[0]);  // assumes a and b are 32-byte aligned.
   __m256 b_vec = _mm256_load_ps(&b[0]);
   __m256 res   = _mm256_addsub_ps(a_vec, b_vec);
   return res;
}
```

compiles just fine for me, with `gcc -march=haswell -O3` (`-march=haswell` implies `-mavx`).  [The asm output is](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m256+foo(const+float+*a,+const+float+*b)%0A%7B%0A+++__m256+a_vec+%3D+_mm256_load_ps(%26a%5B0%5D)%3B++//+assumes+a+and+b+are+aligned.%0A+++__m256+b_vec+%3D+_mm256_load_ps(%26b%5B0%5D)%3B%0A+++__m256+res+++%3D+_mm256_addsub_ps(a_vec,+b_vec)%3B%0A+++return+res%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:44.74730266893812,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell+-ffast-math',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:47.786189304033755,l:'4',m:70.01034126163393,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:29.989658738366074,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:55.25269733106191,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
    vmovaps       ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    vaddsubps     ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
    ret
```

---

Note that `-c` should not be part of `CFLAGS` in a normal Makefile setup.  It should be part of the `.c` to `.o` pattern rule.

Also, you'll get better results from using a more modern compiler.  Ubuntu 12.04 is over 5 years old, and came out while AVX was still very new.  Newer compilers do a better job with recent CPU extensions.  gcc6.3 is a good choice.  gcc7.1 is out, but it's still very new.

Comment: The code looks good on GCC 6.3 when targeting 64-bit, but when you switch to 32-bit, [the optimizer goes stupid](https://godbolt.org/g/v1ypgb). What is that `LEA` instruction doing there?! Other compilers get it correct, so this looks like a GCC code-gen bug, still not fixed in the trunk.

Comment: @CodyGray: yuck.  The save/restore of `ecx` is also insane.  This is different from (but reminds me of) older gcc emitting code to 32B-align the stack even after optimizing away all spills of `__m256` variables.  Hmm, [the `-O1` code](https://godbolt.org/g/9b6Uyj) maybe sheds a tiny bit of light on it: it uses `lea ecx, [esp+8]` / `mov edx, [ecx]` / `mov eax, [ecx+4]` to load the pointer args from the stack.  It looks like gcc is still "thinking" that (for some crazy reason) but then optimizing away some of it.  Have you reported it upstream yet?  If not, I will.

Comment: Thanks, @Cody. I usually have to guess what component to pick, since I'm not an expert on the under-the-hood stuff so IDK which things are RTL and which are middle-end or whatever.  In this case it looks x86-specific, so "target" is a good choice.  If I wasn't sure, I'd mention that in the text so a gcc dev could re-tag it if necessary.

Comment: Okay, finally made time to report this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81274. Perhaps a bit too detailed, but I am used to reporting bugs on MSVC, where 90% of them go over the head of first-tier staff.